# How do I trigger my onSubmit function when the enter key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is supposed to submit when the user presses enter or clicks a button. The big thing is that the user is going to expect to be able to use Enter to submit this form, and the send button is really for only when they notice it's there, and decide to press the button.

My issue is that I have the form setup and all, and I have my submit handler working properly, but I can't seem to capture the enter key for this at all!

first I have my submit function like this:

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.socket.emit('message', this.state.message);
    console.log('emitted');
    this.setState(
      {
        message: '',
      },
      () => {
        // e.target.value = '';
        console.log('state should be cleared.');
      },
    );
  }
```

and my form like this:

```
<Form>
 <FormGroup>
   <div className="chatBoxRow2">
      <input
         type="text"
         name="message"
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.message}
         className="chatBoxOut"
       />
       <Button className="chatBoxButton" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
          Send
       </Button>
     </div>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

I did try to get this done with a solution found here: [react-redux forms github issue.](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form/issues/790)

but to no avail, I still get an refreshed page.....

Comment: You'll need to add a `keydown` event handler on the `document` that checked for `event.which(13)`.

Comment: why is onSubmit on the button? Use the submit handler on the form

Comment: @epascarello just my usual. Not anything that "has to be"

Comment: Good point. I may have misunderstood the submit event entirely until now

Comment: usually users will be typing in the input right, so listen for `onKeyUp` then `evt.which` to get the key code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to `onSubmit` on the form rather than `onclick` on the button. Buttons are type "submit" by default, so clicking it or pressing 'Enter' inside the text field will submit your form.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
 <FormGroup>
   <div className="chatBoxRow2">
      <input
         type="text"
         name="message"
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.message}
         className="chatBoxOut"
       />
       <Button className="chatBoxButton">
          Send
       </Button>
     </div>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor this:

```
<Form>
 <FormGroup>
   <div className="chatBoxRow2">
      <input
         type="text"
         name="message"
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.message}
         className="chatBoxOut"
       />
       <Button className="chatBoxButton" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
          Send
       </Button>
     </div>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

into this:

Send

So where did I get `handleSubmit` from? Well, if you do a `console.log(this.props);` here:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props);
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
 <FormGroup>
   <div className="chatBoxRow2">
      <input
         type="text"
         name="message"
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.message}
         className="chatBoxOut"
       />
       <button className="chatBoxButton">Send</button>
     </div>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
  )
}
```

You will find there are tremendous number of properties inside that `props` object by Redux Form, one in particular, is called `handleSubmit` which is a function we are supposed to call anytime that your form gets submitted and its provided by Redux Form.

Okay, but why not just `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`? Short answer is because now you are using Redux Form.

This new process of calling `onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}` will change how `onSubmit` gets called.

So instead of:

```
onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

You can now do:

```
onSubmit(formValues) {

}
```

You see you no longer have to deal with the `event` object, instead, it will be called with all the values out of your form. So `handleSubmit` handles the `event.preventDefault()` behind the curtain, leaving our `onSubmit()` callback to get called with the `formValues`.